# zshaddhistory(): Must override (to store CWD), but the standard ways break !$

Tags: zsh

I use `!$` a *lot*. `cat some-long-file`. Then I want to edit it. Must use `!$`: `vim !$`

Now with a definition that is like this:

```
zshaddhistory () {
   print -sr "${1%%$'\n'}"
   # some other stuff
   fc -p
}
```

It all mostly seems to work at first (for a few weeks I thought I was good to go), but it quickly became clear that `!$` was not working properly any longer.

I look over `man zshbuiltins` at `fc` and `print`.

But none of it makes enough sense for me to understand just what this `print -sr` `fc -p` madness is.

It appears that `"${1%%$'\n'}"` simply does not do the same thing as the default `zsh` behavior. It saves it in such a way that `!$` (or e.g. `!-5$`) will NOT retrieve the last arg, it retrieves the **entire** command.

What can I do? I've tried taking out the double-quotes, so `$1` gets expanded out. But it still isn't being fully expanded out. Hopefully someone knows exactly what the problem is.

Maybe `print -sr` is simply the wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

Mailing list to the rescue!

glad someone else has been here.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.user/11785

Solution:

`print -Sr`

(not sure I need the `-r` either)